# Signing a Segwit Multisig Transaction

Tags: wallet, segregated-witness, multi-signature

I am creating some test code which can create transactions and sign then, I already could do it with NON-Segwit multisig address, they were signed using my code and broadcasted.
But when I tried with Segwit multisig, I got problems, it was not signing it right.
Can someone walk me through the steps of creating and signing a multisig segwit transaction?

Comment: Can you post how you were trying to sign segwit multisig?

Comment: I was trying to sign the same way as I was signing the traditional multisig wallet, I have the private key and the redeem script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the non-segwit sighash algorithm. This is not correct. Segwit uses a different sighash algorithm as defined in [BIP 143](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki).